# Исправить цикл что бы вывести определенный результат

Tags: c, циклы

мой код на вывод знаков 0 и 1 в строку в шахмотном порядке

```
int main(void) {
int a, b,i, j, count,s;
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);
count = 1;

    for (j = 1; j <= a; j++)
    {
        if (count == 1)
        {
            for(s=0; s<b; s++){ printf("0"); }
        }
        
        else
        {
            for(s=0; s<b; s++) { printf("1"); }
        }
        count = count * -1;
 
    }
return 0;
}
```

На входе:

```
5
3
```

На выходе:

```
000111000111000
```

Но как мне продублировать строку три раза циклом что бы выводило:

```
000111000111000
000111000111000
000111000111000
```

Comment: Непонятно, ну, выведете вот так - это 3, как я понимаю (3 клетки, размера 3x3). А где используется 5? При, скажем, 4 - надо ли вывести 4 строки вида `0000111100001111` или нет? Понимаете, вы свою задачу уже обсосали вдоль и поперек, и вам **кажется**, что в вашей формулировке все понятно - но это понятно вам. Давайте точную формулировку задачи. Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: @Harry исправил чуть описание, как видите, программа выводит поочередно 000 и 111 в шахмотном порядке пять раз в строку

Comment: Ну не легче. А для 6 4 - что должно быть? 3 5 (не 5 3) - что?

Comment: @Harry для 6 4 программа выводит четыре нуля и четыре единицы поочерёдно шесть раз. 
Мне просто нужно продублировать строку на выводе b раз с "\n" после каждой строки "000011110000111100001111"

Comment: @Harry для 3 и 5 соответсвенно 5 знаков по три раза - 000001111100000

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите этого?

```
int main() {
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    for (int row = 0; row < m; ++row) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                printf("%d", i % 2);
            }

        puts("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, на выходе так. только мне нужно 0 и 1 заменить на char  в будущем и этот вариант не совсем подходит. Скажем если я хочу крестики вместо единиц и букву О вместо нулей

Comment: Замените на `printf("%с", (i % 2) ? _sym_1 : _sym_0 );`, где `_sym_0` символ для нолика, а `_sym_1` - для единицы. Неужели же вы до такой степени не знаете C?...

Comment: логично что я не знаю как это сделать, если спрашиваю здесь. К тому же, то что вы написали выше не работает

Comment: Тогда идите берите "С для чайников" и учите. Значит, все, что вы написали выше - **мой код** - ложь, и писали его не вы! Потому что для написания даже кода в вопросе надо иметь хоть какие-то знания. И не врите, что мой код не работает - вот: https://ideone.com/cdFq8j

Comment: слушайте, я писал что это мой код и задал вопрос, я тут в дет садик не играюсь. Смысл этой площадки если все только и будут писать - "с для чайников". На счет врать не врать, посмотрите на пометку в своем комментарии, он первый и находится выше(!important) про него и шел разговор, синтаксис там неправильный явно. То что у вас еще выше, в ответе работает.

Comment: https://ideone.com/K3TMFA